# Floating Label In Vue/Tailwind

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I am hoping to find a floating label for input form fields that puts the label in the border to use in my Tailwind CSS/Vue project.  I've looked at a couple of options:

1. https://csslayout.io/patterns/floating-label/ which simply uses CSS.  It works great outside of Tailwind, but when I import Tailwind it stops working (I have the Tailwind/Forms plugin installed, but that doesn't seem to fix it).  I can't even type the text box after Tailwind is added.  Why is that?
2. https://notiz.dev/blog/floating-form-field-with-tailwindcss is more complicated, but I got it working until I put it inside a div which has a background color and then the placeholder disappears.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I am very much a beginner at Tailwind so I'm guessing I just don't know something basic that would make things work.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue I was having.  The first example needed type=text to be specified in the input element.  It also need the text color to be set to something like text-black.  I'm guessing the issue I was having with the second example will also be solved with setting the text color.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the issue I was having. The first example needed type=text to be specified in the input element. It also need the text color to be set to something like text-black. I'm guessing the issue I was having with the second example will also be solved with setting the text color. Thanks.